# logical to factors (or strings) in data.frame

Tags: r

How can recode logical to factors  (or strings) in data.frame?

```
data <- data.frame(year = c(2015, 2015, 2016, 2016),
               column2 = c(4, NA, 9, 1))


library (dplyr)

missing_data <- data %>%
              count(year, complete.cases(column2)) 

names(missing_data)[2] = "col2"
```

My results:

```
year  col2     n
(dbl) (lgl) (int)
2015 FALSE     1
2015  TRUE     1
2016  TRUE     2
```

What I want:

```
year  col2      n
(dbl)        (int)
2015  unknown    1
2015  known      1
2016  known      2
```

What I tried (in dplyr chain):

```
mutate(col2 = as.factor(col2))
```

Comment: basically the same: `missing_data$col2 <- factor(ifelse(missing_data$col2, "known", "unknown"))` but I do prefer the alternatives of richard lindgren and Procrastinatus Maximus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the obvious method as shown by ***richard lindgren***, you could also do this inside the *dplyr* chain. You can create an numeric index from the logicals `[col2 + 1]` and use that to assign the levels `c('unknown','known')`:

```
dat %>%
  count(year, col2 = complete.cases(column2)) %>%
  mutate(col2 = c('unknown','known')[col2 + 1])
```

or with `ifelse`:

```
dat %>%
  count(year, col2 = complete.cases(column2)) %>%
  mutate(col2 = ifelse(col2,'known','unknown'))
```

which both give:

```
   year    col2     n
  (dbl)   (chr) (int)
1  2015 unknown     1
2  2015   known     1
3  2016   known     2
```

If you want a factor as result, you can wrap it in `factor`: `factor(c('unknown','known')[col2 + 1])` or `factor(ifelse(col2,'known','unknown'))`.

---

If you want to incorporate the method as shown by ***richard lindgren*** in the *dplyr*-chain, you will have to `ungroup` first:

```
dat %>%
  count(year, col2 = complete.cases(column2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(col2 = factor(col2, labels = c('unknown','known')))
```

which will give you the desired result as well.

Answer (score 6):

This one should do it.

```
missing_data$col2 <- factor(missing_data$col2, labels=c("unknown", "known"))
```